# 1049 error PHP7 with XAMMP

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I am using `PHP 7.1.7` and `XAMMP` to build a small application.

I have been getting run ragged with a 1049 error trying to connect to a mySQL database that I created via phpMyAdmin called 'shop' using `mysqli`.

I am confused as the db called 'shop' has definitely been set up in phpMyAdmin as you can see here. Any steering would be appreciated.

[image: phpMyAdmin image of db]

**functions.php**

```
<?php

//create connection

$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','shop');

echo $db->connect_errno; // take error reporting off in production mode
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // turn this off in production mode  -
require 'db/functions.php';


?>





<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" media="all">


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dorman Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = main_wrapper>
        <div class ="header_wrapper"><!-- /. this section here is for our header above-->
            <img src="https://s122939.gridserver.com/clients/concept/logo.svg" class="logo"/>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu_bar"><!-- /. we code our nav bar here aka the UL LI-->
            <ul id ="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="form ">
                <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="search our products" />
                    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>    
        </div>   

        <div class = "content_wrapper"><!-- /. this is our content wrapper container-->    
            <div id ="sidebar">   
                <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>   

                <ul id="cats">   
                    <?php getCats();?> <!-- /. this runs the getCats function in functions.php-->    
                </ul>    

                <div id="sidebar_title">Brands</div>

                <ul id="cats">
                    <li><a href="#">HP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DELL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Motorola</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sony Ericsson</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </div>    

            <div id = "content_area">
                <h3>this is the content area for all of our gear</h3>
            </div>  
        </div>   

        <div id = "footer"><!-- /. this is the footer -->    
            <h3>this is the footer</h3>    
        </div>    
    </div> <!-- /. END OF main_wrapper -->    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: error text, do you have it?

Comment: use localhost in place of the ip? Mysql using a different port as well maybe?

Comment: @u_mulder only on the page from the errorno function. Is there anything I could run in terminal to get a more detailed report. thanks

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs when I use 'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1 the error changes from 1049 to 2002.

Comment: This http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: @u_mulder .2002Connect Error: No such file or directory

Comment: daft question, when you download phpMyAdmin and PHP7 does MYSQL not automatically downloaded

Comment: @wengtee that's true it doesn't but you mentioned you were using xampp, which comes with phpMyAdmin + mysql installed